# Idle timeout on TCP connection - Network load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

We were undecided if to use the NLB or ALB, but ended up choosing the network load balancer because of it’s scalability and speed.

We are now facing an issue, when we have two target machines A and B, and i.e. A’s web server stops working, I can see from aws that A gets marked as unhealthy through the health check endpoint, but since the TCP connection is still alive between my machine and server A, it keeps routing my requests to the unhealthy server until the idle timeout ends and closes the TCP connection

I’ve read on the aws documentation that the idle timeout can be changed for the ALB, but not the NLB since it’s on a lower level

Is there a way of handling this? Why would a client want to keep routing the requests to a dead server just because the TCP connection is still alive?

Comment: Is your question about NLB vs ALB (as stated in the title), or is it about TCP timeouts on NLBs?

Comment: @MarkB just changed it. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure of that behavior? NLBs send TCP resets to clients connected to unhealthy targets. You may be experiencing a health check delay where the NLB believes the target is healthy until the next health check. In this case, you could decrease the health check interval to decrease reset response time.

Comment: @Rafael yes, I’m sure of this.. I can see from the logs the health check returning 500 multiple times around 20 times, but still routing my requests to that server until the idle timeout ends .. sometimes it takes 3 mins others 1 mins.. that’s why I was assuming it was due to the keep alive connection

Comment: According to the docs, the only case that could happen is if all the targets behind the NLB are unhealthy. However, you mentioned that one target is healthy, so without a client-side packet capture, it's hard to tell what's going on. I'm assuming your client is sane and not ignoring the TCP resets, assuming that the NLB is truly sending them.